# Modifying object class while running the code

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, runtime

I have the following code running as it should (albeit not special), but I'm trying to make the number of columns defined to be variable. Ideally, this would be done right here in the class.
Is something like this possible? I'm using 4.8

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        class NodeN
        {
            public string NameN { get; set; }

            public string Column1 { get; set; }
            public string Column2 { get; set; }

            public NodeN(string name,string Col1, string Col2)
            {
                this.NameN = name;
                this.Column1 = Col1;
                this.Column2 = Col2;
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //startup stuff
        }
    }
```

What I'd like to do:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class NodeN
        {
            public string NameN { get; set; }

for (int i = 0; i <= numberofcolumns; i++)
{
    
    //create i column definitions
}
    
            public NodeN(string name, ???? )
            {
                this.NameN = name;
                ????
            }
        }

        public int numberofcolumns

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            numberofcolumns = 4
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible but there are many ways to achieve this. Your question is too broad at the moment and needs more details so that an appropriate answer can be given that fits your exact use case (which is still very much unclear).

Comment: Make the columns an array so you do not need to modify the source.

Comment: Excelent idea jdweng, I'm using a list right now (to keep the size variable) and it works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to generate code at runtime, but this is complicated, and really not what you want to do here.

What you should do is inject some form of collection:

- If you do not need to modify the columns after creation, use a `IReadOnlyList<string>`
- If you need to modify the values, but not the number of columns, use an, array.
- If you need to modify both the values and the number of columns, us a `List<string>`